# Image from URL to PHP upload Function

Tags: php, curl

I've looked all over and can't seem to find the solution to my problem. Any help/pointers will be much appreciated.

I'm attempting to pull an image from a URL source (i.e. https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17990738_10154386783672539_8144154100714177483_n.jpg?oh=8c1c2fb46e8626f58fd76662f3fe6673&oe=59AAE570)

the URL is coming from a larger CURL and I'm parsing out the JSON results into a PHP object array

I can pull the url but when I try and pass the image information to my upload function, it fails both of my checks (image size & image type) and therefore fails to upload

the function below works when manually uploading a file via the HTML file uploader. below is what is typically passd

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
```

Here's the uploader function

```
function upload($file)
{
  $target_dir= "../admin/media/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file['name']);
  $random_number = rand(1000,100000);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


  //Check that file is not empty
  $check = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
  if($check !== false) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    $uploadOk = 0; echo "no image size";
  }

  //Check that file is an image
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
      $uploadOk = 0; echo "not an image file";
  }

  $img_info = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
  $width = $img_info[0];
  $height = $img_info[1];
  $ratio = $width / $height;

  switch ($img_info[2]) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF  : $src = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);  break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG : $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']); break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG  : $src = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);  break;
  }

  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    //UPLOAD ORIGINAL VERSION
    $file_name = $random_number."-".$file['name']."-original";
    $file_name = slugify($file_name);

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
    //string the target folder and file name together
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

    //upload image to server
    imagejpeg($tmp, $target_file . ".jpg");
    $file_name_original = $file_name . ".jpg";

    //UPLOAD THUMBNAIL VERSION
    $file_name = $random_number."-".$file['name']."-thumbnail";
    $file_name = slugify($file_name);

    $min_dim_thumbnail = 300;
    if( $ratio > 1) {
            $new_width = $min_dim_thumbnail*$ratio;
            $new_height = $min_dim_thumbnail;
            $x_center = ($new_width/2) - 150;
            $y_center = 0;
        } else {
            $new_width = $min_dim_thumbnail;
            $new_height = $min_dim_thumbnail/$ratio;
            $x_center = 0;
            $y_center = ($new_height/2) - 150;
        }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    $crop = imagecrop($tmp, ['x' => $x_center, 'y' => $y_center, 'width' => '300', 'height' => '300']);

    $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

    imagejpeg($crop, $target_file . ".jpg");
    $file_name_thumbnail = $file_name . ".jpg";


    //UPLOAD BANNER VERSION
    $file_name = $random_number."-".$file['name']."-banner";
    $file_name = slugify($file_name);

    $min_dim_height = 450;
    $min_dim_width = 800;
    if( $ratio > 1.78) {
            $new_width = $min_dim_height*$ratio;
            $new_height = $min_dim_height;
            $x_center = ($new_width/2) - 400;
            $y_center = 0;
        } else {
            $new_width = $min_dim_width;
            $new_height = $min_dim_width/$ratio;
            $x_center = 0;
            $y_center = ($new_height/2) - 225;
        }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    $crop = imagecrop($tmp, ['x' => $x_center, 'y' => $y_center, 'width' => '800', 'height' => '450']);

    $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

    imagejpeg($crop, $target_file . ".jpg");
    $file_name_banner = $file_name . ".jpg";


  }
  //return the slugified file name to the calling function
  return array($file_name_original, $file_name_banner, $file_name_thumbnail);
}?>
```

Here's the slugify Function

```
<?php
//FUNCTION FOR RETURNING SLUG VALUE FROM A STRING
function slugify($text)
{
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
    // transliterate
       //$text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // remove duplicate -
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);
    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    if (empty($text)) {
        return 'n-a';
    }
    return $text;
}?>
```

And here's the code I'm working with in a separate php file that's attempting to process the upload

```
    $image_url = $value->{'cover'}->{'source'}; //define image source
    $file = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $file['tmp_name'] = $image_url;
    $file['name'] = basename($files['tmp_name']);
    list($image_original, $image_banner, $image_thumbnail) = upload($file); //pass PHP image to our upload function
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to download this file & then pass it onto the upload method

Comment: full disclosure: I am still a super-noob at all of this. can you give me a code example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you just have to assign the same keys instead of the default `$_FILES` array:

```
# Create the two elements that are required for the function
$files['tmp_name'] = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c6/4c/e0/c64ce05bf01ccb3ea8af44de5980cbe4.jpg';
$files['name'] = basename($files['tmp_name']);
# Do the regular upload
upload($files);
```

I haven't tried it, but in theory it should work.

Comment: didn't work... I added the code I'm having trouble with to the bottom of my post. (with your added suggestions).

Comment: I don't have the other functions in this so I can't test it, but the file comes across valid in the gdlib, so it should work fine (depending what `slugify()` does).

Comment: I updated my post to include the slugify() function. I also updated the link example to one that pulled from my cURL result. I noticed the URL make-up was a bit different and I'm not sure if that might be causing it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this would help:

```
$url = 'https://v2.convertapi.com/d/kymp602xvk3qvuwgtst0gllvvc9033tl/image.svg';

$path_parts = pathinfo($url);
$_FILES = [];
$_FILES['file']["name"] = $path_parts['filename'];
$_FILES['file']["tmp_name"] =  $url;
$_FILES['file']["extension"] =  $path_parts['extension'];

//create upload function down here

$target_path = 'uploads';
$dir = $target_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']["full_path"];
$newDir = 'test/'.$_FILES['file']["full_path"];
rename($dir, $newDir); //in my case I use rename instead of move_uploaded_file, on your end please use move_uploaded_file instead

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($path_parts);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
```